# Integrating external services in a microservice architecture

Tags: rest, microservices, netflix-feign

I am developing a bookstore application based on microservices architecture with Spring and Netflix OSS.

I made a shopping service, with all the stuff necessary to buy a book. But I need to integrate with two services.

One service is a shipping service, this is an internal service. Connected through a Feign client.

The other service is an inventory service, this is an external service. Connected through an external library. This is a problem because it's more difficult to mock.

In order to connect with this services from shopping service, I thought that the [adapter pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) was a good idea. I made another service, a shopping adapter service, that is used to connect with the other two services. And with this architecture, I can test the shopping service mocking the adapter service.

But now I think that is a bit awkward solution.

Do you know which is the best architecture to connect with external or internal services?

Answer (score 3):

First, is it correct that’s what I understand?

> Compound Service --(use)--> shipping service
>
> ----------------------------(use)--> inventory service ( this project uses external
>   library )

If it is right, I think it is not difficult to mock.

**Create an inventory microservice project for wrapping external library.**

Because compound service doesn`t need to care what we need to use a certain library for inventory. Your Inventory microservice project just exposes endpoint for using inventory service.

> In the microservices world, services are first class citizens. Microservices expose service endpoints as APIs and abstract all their realization details. The internal implementation logic, architecture, and technologies, including programming language, database, quality of services mechanisms, and more, are completely hidden behind the service API.

Then, You can mock Inventory service at your compound service test code.

```
@Configuration
class MessageHandlerTestConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public InventoryClient inventoryClient() {
    return Mockito.mock(InventoryClient.class);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think creating another microservice which you should maintain and monitor and keep resilient and high available etc. just to have a kind of facade or adapter is a good idea. This statement may be proved wrong for some very special cases but generally if you don't have a context to maintain then it is not a good idea to create a new microservice.

What I could recommend would be directly calling shipping service by paying attention to anti corruption layer pattern which keeps your actual domain's service code clean from other microservice's domain entities.

You can find some more information about anti corruption layer here https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/184464/what-is-an-anti-corruption-layer-and-how-is-it-used